Mixed effects modeling without repeated measures but with nested subjects
I have a dataset with three subjects per 'trial' with each of the three subjects experiencing one of three conditions (A,B,C). I then run 30 trials (1-30)total using 90 subjects. i.e. 1a/1b/1c; 2a/2b/2c; etc. No repeated measures.
I'd like to run a mixed model that tests whether A treatment differs from B differs from C, all while nesting TrialID. This is because there might be time/day effects but within a single trial all subjects are tested at the same time.
If I specify a LMM wherein TrialID is a random factor is this sufficient? IF I specify TrialID and SubjectID I get an error, presumably because there are no repeated measures.
Or do I need to specify SubjectID NESTED WITHIN TrialID somehow?
thanks!

...I forgot to mention that the three Conditions are experimentally determined, i.e. Condition is a fixed factor.

The subjects do bring randomness, and you could think of it as a random effect term like you are trying to do. So in principle you are not wrong to think about relating the subjects to a random noise term.
But in practice, because each measurement has a different unique subject, the random variations from subject to subject are indistinguishable from the random noise which is already estimated by a mixed effects modeling.
Random effects are random terms that reoccur in multiple measurements/observations. In the ordinary regression formula $y_i = a + bx_i + \epsilon_i$, the $\epsilon_i$ is a noise term that differs for each measurement $i$. With random effects you consider noise terms that are the same within a group of measurements.

Thanks @Sextus Empiricus. This confirms my intuition, which is Trial# should be random (since there are 3 subjects each with one measurement within), but no factor for subject. I hope that doing so effectively results in determining if Condition A/B/C differ from each other WITHIN Trial#.
